# What is the difference between Maven build and Maven build... in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I am new to eclipse and programming , so probably a silly question.
According to me build just makes jar file but maven install deploys it to local repo thats m2 .

Also there are two options for  build ->maven build and-> maven build..

Could u explain me the explain mw the difference between two.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Maven Build and Maven install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050651/difference-between-maven-build-and-maven-install)

Answer (score 3):

`maven build...` lets you specify goal and various other build parameter (build profile, offline, update snapshot, other build parameter etc..)

`maven build` is a pre-defined goal that eclipse maven plugin wraps under,

You could see the first couple line of output for both of the case

Comment: In general in Eclipse, when a menu item ends with ellipses (...), it indicates selecting that item will open a dialog or wizard to configure the action or do something else in a modal context. Menu items that don't end in ellipses usually invoke some action directly.

Answer (score 2):

`Build` - Maven phase - compile and prepare ready to distribute package - eg. `JAR`

`Build...` - opens eclipse wizzard where you can customize the build

`Install` - Maven phase - do the same as with `Build` and install to local artifact (product of `Build` phase) to local or remote repository. This will allow to use that project as dependency in other projects.